# Multilevel paragraph numbering in header/footer in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

(I'm not a native English speaker, sorry if my language is not perfect).

I'm using Word to write an essay which uses "Titles" (styles) to obtain a multilevel paragraph numbering, e.g. 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.3.1.1, 1.3.1.2...

I'd like the number of the first title in each page (whatever style it is, "Title 1", "Title 2", etc.) to be shown in the header or footer of the page.

I found [this page by Allen Wyatt](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T008306_Paragraph_Numbers_in_Headers_or_Footers.html) on the Internet, and his method works fine, but only works for *one* kind of title style. I want Word to show the first title in every page, *independently* of the style it is (Title 1, 2, 3...). How can I do?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me.

Comment: Via using the field, you need to determine the style of the first paragraph number on each page, and then enter it in field code.

Answer (score 0):

*I assume that Allen referred you to the [StyleRef field](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#STYLEREF), which is the best way to reference page content in a Header.*

**What you are asking gets much more complex.**

See Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill's page on [Useful StyleRef Tricks](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/StyleRef.htm), the part on suppressing a StyleRef field.

> **Suppressing a StyleRef field**
>
> As we have seen above (Caveat #4), Hidden formatting is the only font
> formatting that a StyleRef field picks up. You can use this to your
> advantage, however, in combination with the default behavior of
> StyleRef fields:
>
> On any given page, a StyleRef field in a header or footer will pick up the first text on the page that is formatted with the
> referenced style.
>
> If there is no text on the page formatted with that style, it will look for the last previous text in that style.
>
> What this means for you is that if you have a heading on one page that
> you want picked up in the headers on subsequent pages but not on the
> page where it appears, you can accomplish this in one of two ways:
>
> You can precede the heading with an empty, Hidden paragraph in the same style. On the first page, Word will pick up the empty paragraph
> (it doesn’t actually have to be Hidden as long as it’s empty, but it
> will need to be Hidden if you don’t want it to take up space). This
> will work for either paragraph or character styles.
>
> You can include some Hidden text at the beginning of the heading and apply the referenced style to it. This will require a character
> style applied carefully. As we saw in Caveat #3 above, Word will pick
> up only the first portion of text formatted with the character style,
> so you will need to insert at least two characters, format both as
> Hidden, and format the first with your referenced style. Then format
> the rest of the paragraph with the character style. Note: Be careful
> not to include the final paragraph mark in the character style; see
> Caveat #2 above.
>
> Important Note: As noted in (1) above, an empty paragraph in the referenced style will be picked up by the StyleRef field. If you ever
> experience problems with missing text in a header or footer that
> contains a StyleRef field, look for these empty paragraphs. It is
> helpful to display nonprinting characters, and you can also use the
> Find dialog to search for the referenced style. One place you may not
> think to look is in tables: keep in mind that the end-of-cell marker
> (¤) functions the same as a paragraph mark. If there is a paragraph
> break before the end of the cell, then an empty paragraph has been
> created.

You would want StyleRef fields for each of the possible styles and then set things up to suppress whichever ones you do not want.

You can find information on editing fields on [my page about fields](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#typefields).